# IntelliJ markdown: how to open localhost links in browser?

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

When I click localhost links in the markdown editor of IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3 nothing happens: i.e. I'd expect the link to be opened in the browser

Links localhost links that end with `.html` work (i.e. the link is opened in the browser)

here is a test-markdown file to illustrate the issue:

```
IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3 (build 30.Nov.2020)

Following links do not work (i.e. the browser is not opened)
* http://127.0.0.1/
* http://127.0.0.1:8080/
* http://127.0.0.1:8080/ngsw/state
* http://localhost:8080/
* http://localhost/
* http://localhost:8080/ngsw/state

Following links work:
* http://127.0.0.1/index.html
* http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html
* http://localhost:8080/index.html
* http://www.google.com
```

Is this a bug or some kind of security setting, that can be changed?

Comment: There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-256993. It has limited visibility at the moment.

Comment: @y.bedrov what does limited visibility mean? i.e. is it some internal issue for IntelliJ staff only? If so: should I create a new public issue?

Comment: @TmTron Feel free to vote for the current one, it's public now.

Comment: Looks like the markdown editor filters out some urls it doesn't think it's a valid url.